# How can I use Regex to match optional characters only if the previous optional character matched?

Tags: python, regex

For example: How do I match the words `kein`, `keine`, `keiner` or `keines` with regex.

I know how I can check for optional characters:

```
\bkein(?:e)?(?:r|s)?\b
```

But this way I would also match `keins` and `keinr` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
\bkein(?:e[rs]?)?\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OVrIBC/1)

**Breakdown:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `kein`: Match `kein`
- `(?:e[rs]?)?`: Optional non-capture group to match `e` or `er` or `es`
- `\b`: Word boundary

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of possible suffixes like:

```
\bkein(e|er|es)?\b
```